# How to set the padding configuration with Huggingface's GenerateMixin's generate method?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

How to set the padding configuration with Huggingface's GenerateMixin's [generate](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/text_generation#transformers.GenerationMixin.generate) method?

I am trying to batch-generate text 16 at a time. While tokenizing I left pad all my sequences and set the pad_token as equal to the eos_token. Since I don't see a link between the generate method and the tokenizer used to tokenize the input, how do I set it up?

Here is a small [code snippet](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/10704#issuecomment-798870853) of what I am trying to do:

```
from transformers import GPT2Tokenizer, GPT2LMHeadModel
import torch

tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained('gpt2')
tokenizer.padding_side = "left" 
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token # to avoid an error
model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained('gpt2')

device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'

texts = ["this is a first prompt", "this is a second prompt"]
encoding = tokenizer(texts, padding=True, return_tensors='pt').to(device)
with torch.no_grad():
    generated_ids = model.generate(**encoding)
generated_texts = tokenizer.batch_decode(generated_ids, skip_special_tokens=True)
```

Two sequences of unequal length look like this rn:

```
[[2, 2, 2, 2, 323, 244, 34, 55, 1, 1, 1, 1]
 [2, 2, 23, 3225, 323, 244, 34, 55, 51, 61, 41, 612]]
```

Where `1` is the `<unk>` token and `2` is `eos_token`

Here is the current behavior when we batch generate:

- The generated text is padded on the right.
- The padding token used by [`generate()`](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/text_generation#transformers.GenerationMixin.generate) is the `<unk>` token of the model's tokenizer.

I want to be able to:

- Change the padding side to `right`.
- Use a different token for padding. For instance the `eos_token` that I already set the tokenizer to use in the snippet above.

Comment: Refer this post for an Answer: 

https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/how-to-set-the-padding-configuration-with-huggingfaces-generatemixins-generate-method/56405/4?u=nasheed